# C++ Deleting objects in vector and replacing them by new objects

Tags: c++, vector

I want to delete objects inside a vector and replace them with new objects in my SFML C++ project. When I run the program, the old objects disappear and nothing appears in their place.
Here's the createObjects function:

```
vector<Object> createObjects(float numberOfObjects) {
    vector<Object> v;
    v.push_back(Object());  
return v;
}
```

And here is the code inside while(window.pollEvent(event)) in main.cpp:

```
if ((event.type == Event::KeyPressed) && (event.key.code == Keyboard::Hyphen)) {
    numberOfObjects--;
    v.clear();
    vector<Object> v = createObjects(numberOfObjects);
}

if ((event.type == Event::KeyPressed) && (event.key.code == Keyboard::Equal)) {
    numberOfObjects++;
    v.clear();
    vector<Objectk> v = createObjects(numberOfObjects);
}
```

Comment: `vector<Objectk> v = createObjects(numberOfObjects);` - You are not using the parameter `numberOfObjects` inside createObjects then why are you having it ?

Comment: `float numberOfObjects` I don't think you would want this to be a `float` if you do indeed actually use the parameter and that `numberOfObjects` is a good name. It's not like you can create 3.1 objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not replacing the original `vector` at all, you are assigning the output of `createObjects()` to a local `vector` that goes out of scope immediately.  You need to get rid of the local `v` variable that you are assigning to, by changing this:

```cpp
vector<Objectk> v = createObjects(numberOfObjects);
```

To this:

```cpp
v = createObjects(numberOfObjects);
```

Like this:

```cpp
if ((event.type == Event::KeyPressed) && (event.key.code == Keyboard::Hyphen)) {
    numberOfObjects--;
    v.clear();
    v = createObjects(numberOfObjects); // <-- HERE
}

if ((event.type == Event::KeyPressed) && (event.key.code == Keyboard::Equal)) {
    numberOfObjects++;
    v.clear();
    v = createObjects(numberOfObjects); // <-- HERE
}
```

---

That being said, there is no need to call `clear()` before calling `createObjects()`, a `vector` automatically clears its old data when being assigned new data, eg:

```cpp
if ((event.type == Event::KeyPressed) && (event.key.code == Keyboard::Hyphen)) {
    numberOfObjects--;
    v = createObjects(numberOfObjects); // <-- HERE
}

if ((event.type == Event::KeyPressed) && (event.key.code == Keyboard::Equal)) {
    numberOfObjects++;
    v = createObjects(numberOfObjects); // <-- HERE
}
```

Even better, there is no need to recreate the `vector` at all, eg:

```cpp
if ((event.type == Event::KeyPressed) && (event.key.code == Keyboard::Hyphen)) {
    if (!v.empty()) {
        // to remove an element from the end...
        v.pop_back();
        // or, to remove an element from the front...
        v.erase(v.begin());
        numberOfObjects--;
    }
}

if ((event.type == Event::KeyPressed) && (event.key.code == Keyboard::Equal)) {
    // to add an element at the end...
    v.push_back(Object());
    // or, to add an element at the front...
    v.insert(v.begin(), Object());
    numberOfObjects++;
}
```

In which case, you could just get rid of `numberOfObjects` altogether and use `v.size()` instead when needed.